# What is this style of design called? It's not still flat is it?

Tags: website-design, interface-design, design-principles, style-identification, style

I'm trying to think of the name of this style, to me, it's sort of like a flat meets minimal skeuomorphism (like 90% flat, 10% skeuomorphism) but I think there's a proper name for this style, just trying to find out what it is.

This is a button:

[image: a button]

This is part of a header:

[image: a header]

Comment: Not everything has a name :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you think "there's a proper name"? It could be either...

or perhaps **isometric** (which would be as accurate as skeuomorphic or flat)

Comment: yeah this seems to be roughly what I was after, a quick google image search of "isometric website design" revealed a lot of memories of habbo hotel, appreciate the quick response :)